# Ionic - Create SQLite database in different directory in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm stuck at creating an SQLite database in a different directory than the default. To describe my problem, I'm using :

[cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin for the sqlite and 
[cordova-file-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) for the file management.

I'm using Ionic3 and Angular5 if that helps.

Here's how my code looks:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

constructor(private sqlite: SQLite, private file: File){

}

createDB(){
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: "maindata.db",
      location: this.file.externalDataDirectory //<---what do I put here?
    }).then((sqliteObj: SQLiteObject) => {
       //success
    }, error => {
       console.log(error);
       //error
    });
}
```

Code above outputs:

> Error: Valid iOS database location could not be determined in
>   openDatabase call at newSQLError

This is what I do not understand, I do not have the ios platform added, I'm using and building this for android platform. Why does it say that this isn't a valid iOS db location. Other parameters for SQLiteDatabaseConfig are : location, iosDatabaseLocation, createFromLocation and key.

Other stuff that I've tried:

```
this.file.applicationDirectory
this.file.externalApplicationDirectory
"/sdcard/"
"/sdcard"
```

and none of them work, only the 'default' works. How do I create my sqlite db file in a custom directory other than default?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem that you got, and I want to know if you finaly find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case of ios there is no external directory. But you trying to access external directory.So it is giving error.
You have to store data into data directory or documents directory.

use `this.file.documentsDirectory` instead of `this.file.externalDataDirectory` or you have to use conditional.

```
if(platform(ios)){
  this.file.documentsDirectory
}else if(platform(android)){`enter code here`
  this.file.externalDataDirectory
}
```